# Bind to Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map from ViewModel

Tags: xaml, dictionary, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms app using a page that displays a map.
The XAML is:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="Map">
    ...
</maps:Map>
```

I know that the map can be accessed from the page's code-behind like this:

```
var position = new Position(37.79762, -122.40181);
Map.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan(position, 0.01, 0.01));
Map.Pins.Add(new Pin
{
    Label = "Xamarin",
    Position = position
});
```

But because this code would break the app's MVVM architecture, I'd rather like to access the `Map` object from my ViewModel, not directly from the View/page - either using it directly like in the above code or by databinding to its properties.

Does anybody know a way how this can be done?

Answer (score 22):

If you don't want to break the MVVM pattern and still be able to access your Map object from the ViewModel then you can expose the Map instance with a property from your ViewModel and bind to it from your View.

Your code should be structured like described here below.

The ViewModel:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace YourApp.ViewModels
{
    public class MapViewModel
    {
        public MapViewModel()
        {
            Map = new Map();
        }

        public Map Map { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

The View (in this example I'm using a `ContentPage` but you can use whatever you like):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourApp.Views.MapView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
                <!--The map-->
                <ContentView Content="{Binding Map}"/>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I didn't show how, but the above code snipped can only work when the ViewModel is the `BindingContext` of your view.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. For those that don't get it - by binding to a property we're still benefitting from the way XAML instandiates things based on types. A much better solution than any of the others.

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks @Aquablue

Answer (score 13):

What about creating a new Control say `BindableMap` which inherits from Map and performs the binding updates which the original `Map` lacks internally. The implementation is pretty straightforward and I have included 2 basic needs; the `Pins` property and the current `MapSpan`. Obviously, you can add your own special needs to this control. All you have to do afterward is to add a property of type `ObservableCollection<Pin>` to your ViewModel and bind it to the PinsSource property of your `BindableMap` in XAML.

Here is the BindableMap:

```
public class BindableMap : Map
{

    public BindableMap()
    {
        PinsSource = new ObservableCollection<Pin>();
    }
    
    public ObservableCollection<Pin> PinsSource
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Pin>)GetValue(PinsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PinsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty PinsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                     propertyName: "PinsSource",
                                                     returnType: typeof(ObservableCollection<Pin>),
                                                     declaringType: typeof(BindableMap),
                                                     defaultValue: null,
                                                     defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                     validateValue: null,
                                                     propertyChanged: PinsSourcePropertyChanged);


    public MapSpan MapSpan
    {
        get { return (MapSpan)GetValue(MapSpanProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MapSpanProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty MapSpanProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                     propertyName: "MapSpan",
                                                     returnType: typeof(MapSpan),
                                                     declaringType: typeof(BindableMap),
                                                     defaultValue: null,
                                                     defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                     validateValue: null,
                                                     propertyChanged: MapSpanPropertyChanged);

    private static void MapSpanPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var thisInstance = bindable as BindableMap;
        var newMapSpan = newValue as MapSpan;

        thisInstance?.MoveToRegion(newMapSpan);
    }
    private static void PinsSourcePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newValue)
    {
        var thisInstance = bindable as BindableMap;
        var newPinsSource = newValue as ObservableCollection<Pin>;

        if (thisInstance == null ||
            newPinsSource == null)
            return;

        UpdatePinsSource(thisInstance, newPinsSource);
        newPinsSource.CollectionChanged += thisInstance.PinsSourceOnCollectionChanged;

    }
    private void PinsSourceOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePinsSource(this, sender as IEnumerable<Pin>);
    }

    private static void UpdatePinsSource(Map bindableMap, IEnumerable<Pin> newSource)
    {
        bindableMap.Pins.Clear();
        foreach (var pin in newSource)
            bindableMap.Pins.Add(pin);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I have omitted the using statements and namespace declaration for the sake of simplicity.
- In order for our original `Pins` property to be updated as we add members to our bindable `PinsSource` property, I declared the `PinsSource` as `ObservableCollection<Pin>` and subscribed to its `CollectionChanged` event. Obviously, you can define it as an `IList` if you intend to only change the whole value of your bound property.

My final word regarding the 2 first answers to this question:

Although having a View control as a ViewModel property exempts us from writing business logic in code behind, but it still feels kind of hacky. In my opinion, the whole point of (well, at least a key point in) the VM part of the MVVM is that it is totally separate and decoupled from the V. Whereas the solution provided in the above-mentioned answers is actually this:

> Insert a View Control into the heart of your ViewModel.

I think this way, not only you break the MVVM pattern but also you break its heart!

Comment: I think your answer makes the most sense here. I implemented this but I am not getting any value in SetValue(PinsSourceProperty, value);. I use   <controls:ExtendedMap MapType="Street" PinsSource="{Binding mappins}" /> in view and mappins is IList<pins> set inside the VM. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @MickeyDhami Does your VM implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and does your `IList<Pin>` property call `NotifyPropertyChanged()` in its `set` section?

Comment: @Pejman I know that this post was long ago, but how to implement custom pins with custom popups?

Comment: @Stefan0309 Well, basically whenever you wanna customize a Xamarin.Forms component beyond the properties provided by the control you have 2 choices: 1) look for a third-party control that fulfills your needs or 2) create a `CustomRenderer` for the control.  If you're not familiar with a `CustomRenderer` you can probably start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/).

Comment: i have the same problem as @MickeyDhami. Can someone help me pls?

Comment: @AlexandruStoica Does your VM implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and does your IList<Pin> property call NotifyPropertyChanged() in its set section?

Comment: yes. it does. Mr Pejman Can I contact you somehow to show my code. Sry if im unpolite but im having this trouble for some time and still can't find an answer.

Comment: Sure @AlexandruStoica. But maybe posting a detailed question in stack overflow help you better. This is my email anyway: `pejman.ebrahimi at outlook.com`.

Comment: The best answer on the internet I saw today. Saved my life. Thank youuuu!

Comment: I appreciate this answer. I used it today. I edited it slightly because I was having problems changing the PinSource contents and not having Pins updated on the Map. When the PinSource changes, it needs the event handler set it seems.

Answer (score 4):

I have two options which worked for me and which could help you.

1. You could either add a static `Xamarin.Forms.Maps Map` property to your `ViewModel` and set this static property after setting the binding context, during the instantiation of your View, as show below:

   ```
   public MapsPage()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           BindingContext = new MapViewModel();
           MapViewModel.Map = MyMap;
       }
   ```

This will permit you to access your Map in your ViewModel.

2. You could pass your Map from your view to the ViewModel during binding, for example:

   ```
   <maps:Map
       x:Name="MyMap"
       IsShowingUser="true"
       MapType="Hybrid" />
   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
       <Button x:Name="HybridButton" Command="{Binding MapToHybridViewChangeCommand}" 
               CommandParameter="{x:Reference MyMap}"
               Text="Hybrid" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="5"/>`
   ```

And get the Map behind from the ViewModel's Command.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `Map.Pins` is not bindable, but there is `ItemsSource`, which is [easy to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/pins#display-a-pin-collection) instead.

```xaml
   <maps:Map ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
        <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <maps:Pin Position="{Binding Position}"
                          Label="{Binding Name}"
                          Address="{Binding Subtitle}" />
```

So, just for the pins, *MVVM* can be done without any custom control.
But `Map.MoveToRegion()` (and `Map.VisibleRegion` to read) is still open. There should be a way to bind them. Why not both in a single read/write property? *(Answer: because of an endless loop.)*

Note: if you need `Map.MoveToRegion` only once on start, the region can be set in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `Pins` is a bindable property on `Map`, you may want to file feature request at Xamarin's [Uservoice](http://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/258559-xamarin-forms-suggestions) or the fourm here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31273/

Answer (score 1):

It is not ideal, but you could listen for the property changed event in the code behind and then apply the change from there. Its a bit manual, but it is doable.

```
((ViewModels.YourViewModel)BindingContext).PropertyChanged += yourPropertyChanged;
```

And then define the "yourPropertyChanged" method

```
private void yourPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == "YourPropertyName")
    {
        var position = new Position(37.79762, -122.40181);
        Map.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan(position, 0.01, 0.01));
        Map.Pins.Add(new Pin
        {
            Label = "Xamarin",
            Position = position
        });
    }
}
```