# Get instance of view registered in Xlabs.ViewFactory

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs, xlabs

Actually I am trying to structure my project in a clean `MVVMV` way. Unfortunately to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098020/bind-to-xamarin-forms-maps-map-from-viewmodel) restriction I need to find a way to set pins to the map without the power `DataBinding`. One workaround could be to have the `View` in my `ViewModel` and set it directly. 
Right now I don't have any chance to get the registered view. Does it make sense to extend the [`XLabs.Forms.Mvvm.ViewFactory`](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Mvvm/ViewFactory.cs)?

Before adding a new issue on GitHub, my hope is that there is a better solution to handle such restrictions. I always used `MVVM` in my (small) WPF projects.

Comment: Maybe using Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter could be enough for your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that doesn't make sense. Your best approach would be to extend the Maps class to make Pins an ObserverableCollection that is bindable.

The new documentation format on the Xamarin site is rather difficult to read and does not provide the information you require at hand like it used to but I believe the Pins object is not bindable.

Take a look at the [Xamarin Forms Labs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) Github project to get an idea of how this can be done. The approach is defined particularly well in the ExtendedPicker classes (here the items are bound to an ObservableCollection).