# How to change MapType of Map in VM?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a map which want to add from VM. I tried to add command when you click on button MapType will be changed.but it does not working.I know how to make it in codebehind.but I need VM

```
ContentView
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            Content="{Binding Map}" />
```

VM

```
        public Map Map { get; set; } 
        public Command StandartMapCommand { get; set; }

        public Command SatelliteMapCommand { get; set; }

        public Command HybridMapCommand { get; set; }
      public MasterPageVM()
        {
             Map = new Map();
           StandartMapCommand = new Command(StandardSelected);
            SatelliteMapCommand = new Command(SatelliteSelected);
            HybridMapCommand = new Command(HybridSelected);
       }
   public void StandardSelected()
        {
         
                Map.MapType = Xamarin.Forms.Maps.MapType.Street;

           
        }

        public void HybridSelected()
        {
        
                Map.MapType = Xamarin.Forms.Maps.MapType.Hybrid;
            }

        

        public void SatelliteSelected()
        {
         
                Map.MapType = Xamarin.Forms.Maps.MapType.Satellite;

        }
```

When I click on button map does not change MapType.pls help

Comment: why does your VM contain a Map object?

Comment: I want to make a map and commands to it, such as changing the type of map or adding pins, the appearance of content view if you click on the pin and I want to do it all in VM, so I decided to add in VM and I saw  example there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098020/bind-to-xamarin-forms-maps-map-from-viewmodel

Comment: please tell me if there is a difference in the performance of the app for example if I do everything in code-behind or VM

Comment: that's a horrible suggestion.  The Map is a UI control and belongs in the View, not the VM.  You can bind the Maps properties and Commands to the VM, but the Map itself should not be in the VM.

Comment: please tell me if there is a difference in the performance of the app for example if I do everything in code-behind or VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a map which want to add from VM. I tried to add command when you click on button MapType will be changed.but it does not working.I know how to make it in codebehind.but I need VM

If you want to change Map.Maptype in viewmodel, you can take a look the following code.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ContentView Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Content="{Binding Map}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Command="{Binding StandartMapCommand}"
            Text="Street" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn2"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Command="{Binding SatelliteMapCommand}"
            Text="Satellite" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn3"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Command="{Binding HybridMapCommand}"
            Text="Hybrid" />

    </Grid>


</ContentPage.Content>

public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();         
        this.BindingContext = new MapViewModel();
    }
}
public class MapViewModel
{
    private Map _map;
    public Map Map
    {
        get { return _map; }
        set
        {
            _map = value;
                    
        }
    }
    public Command StandartMapCommand { get; set; }
    public Command SatelliteMapCommand { get; set; }
    public Command HybridMapCommand { get; set; }
    public MapViewModel()
    {
        Map = new Map();
        Position position = new Position(36.9628066, -122.0194722);
        MapSpan mapSpan = new MapSpan(position, 0.01, 0.01);
        Map.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
        Map.Pins.Add(new Pin
        {
            Label = "Xamarin",
            Position = position
        });

        StandartMapCommand = new Command(streetcommand);
        SatelliteMapCommand = new Command(Satellitecommand);
        HybridMapCommand = new Command(Hybridcommand);
      
    }

    private void streetcommand()
    {
        Map.MapType = MapType.Street;
    }
    private void Satellitecommand()
    {
        Map.MapType = MapType.Satellite;
    }
    private void Hybridcommand()
    {
        Map.MapType = MapType.Hybrid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still does not work for some reason. The map and pin are displayed, but the commands do not change the map type

Comment: @Mykola2012 It has no problem when I changed maptype by button command.You can provide one sample at github , I will download your sample to test.