# Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps Bind MoveToRegion from ViewModel

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, mvvm

Im looking to Bind the Map instance in my view from the ViewModel, specifically the MoveToRegion.
I'm able to bind the Pins from an ObservableCollection in my ViewModel like so:

**View Xaml :**

```
  <maps:Map
    x:Name="mapView"
    HasRotationEnabled="False"
    HeightRequest="180"
    MapType="Street"
    MyLocationEnabled="True">
      <maps:Map.Behaviors>
         <bindings:BindingPinsBehavior Value="{Binding Pins}" />
      </maps:Map.Behaviors>
   </maps:Map>
```

**View Model:**

```
ObservableCollection<Pin> _pins;

    public ObservableCollection<Pin> Pins
    {
        get => _pins;

        set => SetProperty(ref _pins, value);
    }

    public override void Init(ClinicViewModel parameter)
    {
        LoadData(parameter);
    }



    private void LoadData(ClinicViewModel clinic)
    {
       
        Pin clinicPin = new Pin()
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Label = clinic.Name,
            Address = clinic.CompleteAddress,
            Position = new Position(Convert.ToDouble(clinic.Latitude), Convert.ToDouble(clinic.Longitude)),
            Tag = "id_" + clinic.Id

        };


        Pins.Add(clinicPin);
    }
```

This works great, but I'm unsure how I can Set the Maps MoveToRegion, as I want to set the map's location to the clinic's longitude and latitude, same as the Pin.

Comment: is `BindingPinsBehavior` your own code, or a nuget package?  AFAIK the standard `VisibleRegion` property is not bindable

Comment: I used Nuget Package for Pins - Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Bindings that allow me to bind an ObervableCollection of Pins to the Map, It works well, but no ItemSource to set the MoveToRegion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I have this working now, on Android I've tested and it works Ok, will comment on here once I know IOS is working as should.

I used this SO answer to base my work on, so credit to them (Pejeman) for posting - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53804163/676875

I also used this NuGet package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Bindings/ and GitHub link here - https://github.com/nuitsjp/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Bindings

My Code:

**View:**

```
 <Frame
            Margin="15,0,15,0"
            Padding="0"
            CornerRadius="10"
            IsClippedToBounds="True">
            <map:BindableMap
                x:Name="mapView"
                HasRotationEnabled="False"
                HeightRequest="180"
                MapSpan="{Binding ClinicMapSpan}"
                MapType="Street"
                MyLocationEnabled="True">
                <maps:Map.Behaviors>
                    <bindings:BindingPinsBehavior Value="{Binding Pins}" />
                </maps:Map.Behaviors>
            </map:BindableMap>
        </Frame>
```

**View Model**

```
ObservableCollection<Pin> _pins;

    public ObservableCollection<Pin> Pins
    {
        get => _pins;

        set => SetProperty(ref _pins, value);
    }
    public override void Init(ClinicViewModel parameter)
    {
        LoadData(parameter);
    }

    private void LoadData(ClinicViewModel clinic)
    {
       
        try
        {
            Pin clinicPin = new Pin()
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Label = clinic.Name,
                Address = clinic.CompleteAddress,
                Position = new Position(Convert.ToDouble(clinic.Latitude), Convert.ToDouble(clinic.Longitude)),
                Tag = "id_" + clinic.Id

            };

            ClinicMapSpan = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(clinicPin.Position.Latitude, clinicPin.Position.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(1));
            Pins.Add(clinicPin);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            AnalyticService.TrackEvent("Clinic Details", new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Method", clinic.ClinicName + " ClinicDetailViewModel.LoadData" }
        });

        }


    }
```

**Custom BindableMap**

```
 public class BindableMap : Map
{

    public BindableMap()
    {
        PinsSource = new ObservableCollection<Pin>();
        PinsSource.CollectionChanged += PinsSourceOnCollectionChanged;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Pin> PinsSource
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Pin>)GetValue(PinsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PinsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty PinsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                     propertyName: "PinsSource",
                                                     returnType: typeof(ObservableCollection<Pin>),
                                                     declaringType: typeof(BindableMap),
                                                     defaultValue: null,
                                                     defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                     validateValue: null,
                                                     propertyChanged: PinsSourcePropertyChanged);


    public MapSpan MapSpan
    {
        get { return (MapSpan)GetValue(MapSpanProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MapSpanProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty MapSpanProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                     propertyName: "MapSpan",
                                                     returnType: typeof(MapSpan),
                                                     declaringType: typeof(BindableMap),
                                                     defaultValue: null,
                                                     defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                     validateValue: null,
                                                     propertyChanged: MapSpanPropertyChanged);

    private static void MapSpanPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var thisInstance = bindable as BindableMap;
        var newMapSpan = newValue as MapSpan;

        thisInstance?.MoveToRegion(newMapSpan);
    }
    private static void PinsSourcePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newValue)
    {
        var thisInstance = bindable as BindableMap;
        var newPinsSource = newValue as ObservableCollection<Pin>;

        if (thisInstance == null ||
            newPinsSource == null)
            return;

        UpdatePinsSource(thisInstance, newPinsSource);
    }
    private void PinsSourceOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePinsSource(this, sender as IEnumerable<Pin>);
    }

    private static void UpdatePinsSource(Map bindableMap, IEnumerable<Pin> newSource)
    {
        bindableMap.Pins.Clear();
        foreach (var pin in newSource)
            bindableMap.Pins.Add(pin);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone. I also found this YouTube Video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icMM2cviOJo (It's in Spanish) I've yet to watch it but it does show how to bind a Google Map MVVM.

Comment: At least for the pins this is all not necessary, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69545249/1855801 (and if you only need to set the region once at start, this can be done in the constructor)