# Binding Location to .net MAUI MAP

Tags: .net, maui

I want to show A map,

Coordinates is getting on page load.

Map code:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="map" WidthRequest="296" HeightRequest="192" Margin="0,24,0,0" 
              MapType="Street" IsZoomEnabled="False" IsScrollEnabled="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedBikeSensorData}">
        <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <maps:Pin Label="Fiets Locatie"
                          Address="{Binding SelectedBikeSensorData.LatestAdress}"
                          Type="Place"
                          Location="{Binding SelectedBikeSensorData.Locatie}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
    </maps:Map>
```

MVVM Commando

```
    [RelayCommand]
    async void GetBikeInformation()
    {
        var data = await _userService.GetBikeLocationAsync(SelectedFiets);
        if (data != null)
        {
            SelectedBikeSensorData = new MapData
            {
                TrackerId = data.serial,
                Locatie = new Location(data.lastLat, data.lastLng),
                Lat = data.lastLat,
                Long = data.lastLng,
                LatestAdress = data.lastAddress
            };
        }
```

SelectedBikeSensorData is a type MapData:

```
 public class MapData
{
    public string TrackerId { get; set; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Long { get; set; }
    public Location Locatie { get; set; }
    public string LatestAdress { get; set; }
}
```

MAPVIEW ANDROID: https://ibb.co/R2Jjx5S

Someone that maybe knows what the problem?

Thanks In Advance!

**UPDATE:**

New XAML Code:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="map" WidthRequest="296" HeightRequest="192" Margin="0,24,0,0" 
              MapType="Hybrid" IsZoomEnabled="True" IsScrollEnabled="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}">
        <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <maps:Pin Label="Fiets Locatie"
                      Address="{Binding LatestAdress}"
                      Type="Place"
                      Location="{Binding Locatie}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
```

MVVM Commando:

```
[RelayCommand]
    async void GetBikeInformation()
    {
        var data = await _userService.GetBikeLocationAsync(SelectedFiets);
        if (data != null)
        {
            _positions = new ObservableCollection<MapData>();
            _positions.Add(new MapData
            {
                Long = data.lastLng,
                Lat = data.lastLat,
                LatestAdress = data.lastAddress,
                Locatie = new Location(data.lastLat,data.lastLng),
                TrackerId = data.serial,
            });

            SelectedBikeSensorData = new MapData
            {
                LatestAdress = data.lastAddress
            };

            
        }
    }
```

Add this to my viewmodel:

```
ObservableCollection<MapData> _positions;

public IEnumerable<MapData> Positions => _positions;
```

In mine viewmodel constructor I added this line of code:

```
_positions = new ObservableCollection<MapData>();
```

Binding the viewmodel to my view:

```
 public BikeInformationPage(BikeDetailsViewModel bikeDetailsViewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = bikeDetailsViewModel;

}
```

Data in Positions:
[image]

Data in Positions => Location:
[image]

Comment: `ItemsSource` must be an `IEnumerable<T>`.  You have it bound to a single `MapData` object

Comment: Also not working, I added some new code

Comment: “Not working” doesn’t tell us anything useful.  What is the specific problem you’re having?

Comment: It's not showing anythin, If you read the original post you should see now that I have an IEnumerable Positions, If I add an Position to it, it doesn't show anything on my map

Comment: Are you navigating and zooming to the correct point on the map?  Just adding a pin does not change the default map location.

Comment: Yes, I catch my address in a Label undernead the map. Thats correct so i navigate Belgium on the map but don't see any pins

Comment: Is the Pins collection on the Map being populated?

Comment: I find the problem. I will discribe it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

I created this in my ViewModel:

```
ObservableCollection<MapData> _positions;

public IEnumerable<MapData> Positions => _positions;
```

I did this on the answer of @Jessie Zhang -MSFT

Because I use the community toolkit.MVVM package I din't get the positions in my view.

To test this I created a Collection view to the test this:

```
<CollectionView Margin="0,16,0,0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}"
        SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:MapData">
                <VerticalStackLayout WidthRequest="296" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="250" Margin="0,12,0,12" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
                    <Frame>
                        <VerticalStackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding LatestAdress}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Lat}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Long}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Locatie}"/>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

In my viewmodel I deleted:

```
ObservableCollection<MapData> _positions;

public IEnumerable<MapData> Positions => _positions;
```

I add then:

```
[ObservableProperty]
ObservableCollection<MapData> positions;
```

Now I am getting data in my view:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just as Jason said, the `ItemsSource` should be an `IEnumerable<T>` which specifies the collection of `IEnumerable` pin items to be displayed. But in your code, you bound a single `MapData` object to it.

For this, you can refer to the official document [Display a pin collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-7.0#display-a-pin-collection).

You can refer to the following code:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps">    
    <Grid>
        ...
        <maps:Map x:Name="map"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}">
            <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <maps:Pin Location="{Binding Location}"
                              Address="{Binding Address}"
                              Label="{Binding Description}" />
                </DataTemplate>    
            </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
        </maps:Map>
        ...
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

And there is an official sample about this, you can check it [.NET MAUI - Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/maui-samples/userinterface-map/).

Please pay attention to [PinItemsSourcePage.xaml.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/Map/MapDemo/WorkingWithMaps/Views/PinItemsSourcePage.xaml.cs), [PinItemsSourcePage.xaml](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/Map/MapDemo/WorkingWithMaps/Views/PinItemsSourcePage.xaml) and [PinItemsSourcePageViewModel.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/Map/MapDemo/WorkingWithMaps/ViewModels/PinItemsSourcePageViewModel.cs).

Comment: Did this, will update the code I have now. Still not working!

Comment: I couldn't see the other code, but you can recheck if you have set the `BindingContext ` for your page. And you can also check if  `Positions` has the right data.

Comment: I added in my original post the code I have right now, You can also see whats in Positions

Comment: Have  you generated an API key for your android app, which will be consumed by the [Google Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk) on which the Map control relies on Android. To do this, follow the instructions in [Set up in the Google Cloud Console](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/cloud-setup) and [Use API Keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key) on developers.google.com.

Comment: Yes, I first tried a static location.  Like the example of microsoft.  That worked so I don't think it is anything with the API Key..

Comment: Find the problem, It was because I use the community toolkit.mvvm
I will discribe it as an answer

Comment: I have still a question. How can I implement that my maps goes to the Pin? I saw that you could do map.movetoregion but this is in my xaml.cs
Is their some solution that I can also do that with binding?

Comment: For this, you can refer to this thread: [Bind to Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map from ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68487703/xamarin-forms-googlemaps-bind-movetoregion-from-viewmodel).